# bash open a vi and then execute a vi register

Tags: bash, shell, vim, vi

I am currently trying to make a script that will take any number of arguments and create files for them. I have some registers saved in vi that I already have loaded with generic things I want in each file type.
So, I know that my shell can enter a file by typing vi "filename" but I am wondering if there is a way I could execute a register and then close the file, I suppose I could use my shell to append things I want to but it seems much more tedious which I am happy to do if you guys don't have any hints.

P.S. I have been looking online for way to open multiple tabs in the same terminal with only having generic Ubuntu without having to open a new terminal. But I think the only way to make this possibly happen is through programs I have to install, correct? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you actually want to achieve; please be more specific and add concrete examples. And don't ask more (unrelated) questions here! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to open files in an **already-open** execution of vim, then I think that'd have to be two processes:

1. outside process: to create the files *(the one you planned to create)*
2. inside process: (in your already opened vim) to load newly-appeared files *(eg: like an automated `:e new/file.txt`)*

wrt your PS: multiple files (**buffers**) is doable by default; a **quickstart**:

- you can [watch](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-buffers/) or [read this screencast](http://vimcasts.org/transcripts/6/en/) more about "buffers"
- definitely shouldn't need new software
- try this out yourself: `vim ./foo ./bar` *(in a terminal)*

  - `:ls` to see buffers you've opened *(you'll see "foo" and "bar)*
  - `:buffer N` to jump to one of said buffers

wrt "tabs" -- is that so that you can click? If so, maybe reconsider using vi *(but if you're sticking to vi: you can find documentation to get tab-like UI if you really want, and again: no extra software)*.